# React Native detect if a component is dragged into another component

Tags: android, react-native

I need to detect if component A's position is within component B when pan gesture (drag) on A is released.

However, the position from `onPanResponderRelease`'s `gesture.moveY` is measured with respect to the entire screen, whereas the position returned from A's `onLayout`is measured with respect to the parent view.

So i'd need to know the parent view's current height to reconcile the differences. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nativeEvent.locationX` and `nativeEvent.locationY` instead of the `moveX` and `moveY` and you will get the relative position to the parent.

[Related documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html)